# Check that the request returned to the database

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have a method that makes a query to the database.
I want to understand. How can I check if there are rows in the table that meet my condition?

```
def getMessage() = {
  val query = messages.filter(_.status === true)
  val action = query.result.head
  val result = db.run(action)
  //val sql = action.statements.head
  val temp = result.map(_.phone)
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  println(temp.toString)
 }
```

For example, I need an example logic of how the method works.

```
    def getMessage():String = {
     val query = messages.filter(_.status === true)
     val action = query.result.head
     val result = db.run(action)
     //val sql = action.statements.head
     val temp = result.map(_.phone)
     Thread.sleep(3000)
     
     if (temp != "null") return temp
     else return "null"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.run` returns a `Future` so you need to check the result when that completes:

```
db.run(action).onComplete{
  case Success(res) =>
    // Process result in res
  case Failure(e) =>
    // Handle error case
}
```

You should never `Sleep` or wait for a `Future`, so `getMessage` should return `Future[String]` and the calling code can handle the result when it is ready.

```
def getMessage(): Future[String] = {
 val query = messages.filter(_.status === true)
 val action = query.result.head
 
 db.run(action)
}
```

More generally you need to look at a how `Future` works and how to modify the results (`map`), chain multiple `Future`s (`flatMap`) or handle multiple `Future`s as a single `Future` (`Future.sequence`).

In general you should keep the processing inside the `Future` for as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks for you answear! Yes, i see in documentation about taboo on using method Sleep. I need try return the phone value from the map method. I temporary used Sleep. Otherwise, i get Future<not completed>. You method onComplite is very nice. Now i can handle the exception NullPointException. Due to the application logic, i will often cath such exception.